# "Thank you very much" vs "thank you so much"

Tags: grammar

Would you briefly explain the use of the following wish in different perspective with various examples please?

Comment: It's not only the same question, it's the same OP!!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "Thank you very much" is slightly more formal than "Thank you so much."

Answer (score 0):

The two are synonymous.  No one would really blink at one being used over another, but usually most people would just say "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

The latter one sound more childish

> Wow, dad, thank you so much!

(Eventually with emphasis on ***so***)

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly use the former, although the latter is probably accepted in common speech.

I only the construction *so [adjective]* in conjunction with *that*. Someone can be "so hungry that he could eat an elephant," but not just "so hungry." In the same manner, the latter seems to be thanking the recipient *so much that*… and the reader is left hanging.